# contains in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Hi i am using entity framework and LinQ. I have a table objects called users . i have a list called userids. i have to find all users where ids contains in the string. I have to do following operations ...

```
select * from users where userid in (userids);
```

I tried to solve this like this

```
var u = context.users.Where(o=> usersid.Contains(o=> o.userid)).Select(o=> o);
```

but it gives compilation error. how to solve this ?

Comment: Your code uses commas instead of periods, and is in the wrong case. C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
protected Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
            if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }

            if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

            ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

            if (!values.Any())
            {
                return e => false;
            }

            var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

            var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

call the method like this :

```
var u = context.users.Where(BuildContainsExpression<user, Int32>(e => e.Userid, userids)).ToList();
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This is overkill. Writing the linq query to use `Contains()` correctly should suffice. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8421700/134445) for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Put periods instead of commas.

Try

```
var u = context.users.Where(o=> usersid.Contains(o=> o.userid)).Select(o=> o);
```

Comment: sorry for typing mistake. please replace ',' to '.'. But this give error may be its a entityframe work limitation.

Comment: What about the case? you had .contains and .select instead of .Contains and .Select and unlike Visual Basic, C# is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
var u = context.users,Where(o=> usersid.contains(o=> o.userid)),select(o=> o);
```

Assuming that this is the code you are using

```
var u = context.users.Where(o=> usersid.Contains(o => o.userid)).Select(o => o);
```

make sure that you are using `.` instead of `,` and that you have the correct case on your  Methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming userids is an `IEnumerable` of the same type as `User.userid`, try changing your LINQ query to:

```
var u = context.users.Where(o=> userids.Contains(o.userid));
```